# replace all 404 status code by 200 with cakephp 3.9

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

On the front-end, I have a SPA that handles all requests (including 404 pages).

On the backend, I use CakePHP 3.9. I use it as a headless CMS. I want to avoid that Cakephp returns a 404 status code. Instead of that, I want to return a code 200 even if the page is "not found" on the backend side. How can I do this?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It just misleads whatever is making the request to it

Comment: You implement your own exception handler and just return 200 or you do it at the middleware layer and just rewrite 404s to 200s. The more practical option is to have your frontend properly deal with 404s.

Comment: @ADyson> Because the pages are handled by vue-router (vuejs). If the page does not exist, the user will get an error page. it's easier for me to manage everything via vue-router

Comment: @Kisaragi> May I ask you to provide an example please ?

Comment: Read the cake docs to go that route: https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/development/errors.html, find the docs for whatever is serving the request and find how to rewrite status codes.

Comment: @Kisaragi> I did. And unless I misunderstood something, the documentation asks to add "use App\Error\AppError;" in "bootstrap.php". However , when I do that I get "Class 'App\Error\AppError' not found"

Answer (score 0):

can be cleaner, but it works:

```
    //edit file: \src\Controller\ErrorController.php
    public function beforeRender(Event $event)
    {
        //add this:
        if($this->response->getStatusCode() == 404){
            $this->response->statusCode('200');
        }
        parent::beforeRender($event);
        $this->viewBuilder()->setTemplatePath('Error');
    }
```